# How to negate a sentence

Tags: negation

I'm kind of lost here.

In a software that I'm programming it has a condition that when satisfied will not execute the profiles, none, not a single one.

How to correctly express this?

> "Will not run the profiles"

> "Will run no profiles"

Comment: *Software* is an uncountable noun and can't take the indefinite article.  You can find this out by doing a Google search for "Is the word _____ countable".

Comment: Hello 0x3333 and welcome to ELL. We're pretty strict here about asking only one question at a time. Please edit your question (using the small "Edit" button below the question) to only ask one thing, then request for it to be reopened. If you really want an answer to the other thing too, start another new question for it. Also, we require that people asking questions try to answer their questions on their own first. Your question about "a" is probably easy to find an answer to on your own or in other questions on this site

Comment: Sorry for the troubles. I didn’t quite understand the countable problem. Noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to negate

> "It will run the profiles"?

The use of the definite article indicates that there are some profiles we are talking about. (If you omit the definite article that changes the meaning.)

The simplest way to do the negation is just to insert "not":

> It will *not* run the profiles.

This means exactly the opposite - the profiles  we are talking about will not be run.

If you say:

> It will run no profiles

that means that it will not just run none of the profiles we are talking about, but no others either. This usually means the same thing, but it is not the exact logical opposite of what was said.

Comment: I choose this one as the answer just because it clarified that it implies that it will not run just the specified profiles but no others either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible.

For example if there is an empty field, you might say

> There are no sheep in the field.

> There aren't any sheep in the field.

And the meaning is more-or-less the same

Similarly, If your reader understands which profiles you are referring to:

> It will run no profiles.

> It won't run any profiles.

> It won't run the profiles.

All mean roughly the same.  But generally prefer the negated verb "It won't run any...".